# What is wrong with these equations? Undefined control sequence

Tags: equations, errors

I'm using overleaf and when I write these two equations it gives the error: Undefined control sequence
But I can't find anything wrong.

these are the equations:

```
\begin{equation}
    Ax = b, \qquad A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \underset{x}{min} \left \| Ax-b \right \|_{2}, \qquad \qquad A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \qquad \qquad m> n
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Did you load `amssymb` or `amsfonts`? Besides, `\min_{x}` is definitely better than `\underset{x}{min}`

Comment: no...I don't have this package, only amsmath and mathtools. Thank you, now the error is gone

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by failure to use a necessary package.

Answer (score 1):

As @egreg mentioned, it was missing a package: amssymb.

Comment: note that this was an error in code not shown (`\underset`  for example would be undefined if you don't load `amsmath`)